# How to use HTML Variable with setText in Android?

Tags: java, android, spanned

I, want to convert my TextView in Html format. when required. so i used the following code. but i am not getting how to use result variable with setText.

```
@Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        groupDeals.addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                                           @Override
                                           public void onEvent(@javax.annotation.Nullable DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, @javax.annotation.Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
                                               if (e != null) {
                                                   return;
                                               }
                                               if (documentSnapshot.exists()) {

                                                   String title = documentSnapshot.getString(GROUP_DEALS_KEY_DEALS);

                                                   Spanned result;

                                                   if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                                                       result = Html.fromHtml(GROUP_DEALS_KEY_DEALS, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY);
                                                   } else {
                                                       result = Html.fromHtml(GROUP_DEALS_KEY_DEALS);
                                                   }
                                                   tv_groupDeals.setText(title);

                                               }
                                           }
                                       }

        );
    }
```

I, have tried the some solutions. but not getting appropriate result. i tried like this:

```
tv_groupDeals.setText(title + result);
```

But it does't work.

Comment: Hi. You should specify what is not working. 
what is tv_groupDeals object?

Answer (score 0):

I believe **GROUP_DEALS_KEY_DEALS** is not a HTML text to begin with, you can only use a HTML string in **HTML.fromHtml()** methods.

checkout this [link](https://www.stacktips.com/tutorials/android/display-html-in-android-textview) to know how to use HTML strings in TextView.